# Extracting specific strings from IP multimedia data

Tags: text-processing

Have a file with the below data.

What I need is the combination of `IMPU` and `IMPI` from the block of data available. Now, this type of data is available in around 25 huge-size files, and it needs to be filtered from all.

There can be a possibility that in some blocks only `IMPU` is present.

I need the data in below format:

```
IMPU : XXXXXXXXXXXXX , IMPI : YYYYYYYYYYYYY , mscId : nakjsxabjk1nbjk23e32jked
```

```
dn: IMPU=tel:\csasacas,serv=IMS,assocId=csacsa,ou=associations,dc=cl
structuralObjectClass: csacascsa
objectClass: cascascsa
entryDS: cascasc
nodeId: ascasc
createTimestamp: csaccascas
modifyTimestamp: casc
IMPU: tel:+XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ImsIrs: cascasc
ImsSessBarrInd: cascas
ImsIsDefault: csac
ImsMaxNumberOfContacts: 1
mscID : nakjsxabjk1nbjk23e32jked

dn: serv=Identities,mscId=csac,ou=multiSCs,dc=cl
structuralObjectClass: casc
objectClass: csac
objectClass: sacas
entryDS: csaas
nodeId: csac
createTimestamp: sacsa
modifyTimestamp: ascsac
serv: cascas
CDC: csacsa
IMSI: scsacdascs
imsiMask: cacssacas
MSISDN: cdsacsacd
msisdnMask: csaascdas
IMPI: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY@ims.mnc005.mcc724.3gppnetwork.org
impiMask: aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Are you showing one or two "blocks" in your question? How may I tell these lines of data apart from many other similar lines of data and how do I know that the `IMPU` and `mscId` lines from the first part belongs together with the `IMPI` lines from the second half?

Comment: Thankyou for going through the question. there is a file with millions of lines in it. One block may have around 100-150 lines as shown above....Now within  these 100-150 lines, lies the IMPU, PMI and mscId and other parameters out of which i need IMPU, IMPI and mscId, may be other which I can add later....What i need is a combination of IMPU, IMPI and mscId from these 100-150 lines for all the numbers present in  a file having millions of similar lines. ..plz help

Comment: That much is clear. The question still stands though: In the text, you show what appears to be two "blocks". Even though these are two separate blocks, you appear to want specific data from both of these (merged together in one line). My question is how we may tell that these two blocks are related, and how they are distinguished from any other of the million lines in the in-data.  I'm assuming you want several lines of output in the end, right? Or do you just want the first instance of `IMPU`, `mscId`, and `IMPI`?

Comment: OK, thanks...for one number X every block starts with "dn:" and there are around 8-14 dn: blocks, vary from number to number.
in this set of blocks there are IMPU, IMPI and mscId like parameters in a different dn: blocks of a number say X.
now I need data like below seperated by comma, may be like IMPU and its value in front of it, then IMPI and its value in one line from all set of numbers having these dn: blocks varying in count for every number...20-25 files are .gz format
IMPU: tel:+XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX , IMPI: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY@ims.mnc0XXX.mccXXX.3gppnetwork.org , mscId=XXXXXXX

Comment: Please don't add requirements and/or examples in comments where they can't be formatted and can be missed. [edit] your question to include all relevant information and make sure your example covers all the use cases you need it to.

Comment: After this much time, though, you may be better off accepting an answer to the question you asked and asking a new question that covers your new requirements as it's unlikely anyone will still be looking at this question.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have tag-value pairs in your input I find it best to first create an array mapping the tags (names) to values then you can print whatever values you like in whatever order you like by their tags:

```
$ awk -F'[: +]+' -v OFS=' , ' '
    { sub(/@.*/,""); f[$1] = $1 " : " $NF }
    END { print f["IMPU"], f["IMPI"], f["mscID"] }
' file
IMPU : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX , IMPI : YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY , mscID : nakjsxabjk1nbjk23e32jked
```

Comment: thanks for sharing but this isn't working it seems...tried creating a .sh file, entered this script along with the file name. but no result. This is just a sample block for one number with many lines in it may be...and in one file i have a million of data, means many lines in it...and similarly i have 20-25 files.....what i need is to extract a couple of parameters from all files...files are in .gz format.....
above given i tried after gunzipping it...but please give me a command for .gz file where I can extract these data from all the .gz files at once

Comment: `gunzip file.gz | awk 'script'` but that parts trivial, don't muddy your question talking about gzip-ed files when you just have to gunzip them to get flat text files for awk to run on. As you can see in my answer the script does what you asked for given the input/output you provided so if it doesn't do what you really need then edit your question to fix your sample input/output to reflect what you really need and included cases where my answer doesn't do that.

Comment: Ok ED Morton....One query....What if One IMPU's IMPI can be in other gunzipped filed..
I mean...i need to look only for those IMPUs which start with "sip:+", for eg "sip:+XXXXXXXXXXX@ims.mncaaa.mccbbb.3gppnetwork.org" and IMPI associated to it "IMPI: YYYYYYYYY@ims.mncaaa.mccbbb.3gppnetwork.org" and these combination can exist in any of the gunzipped file....the above two parameters are co-related on the basis of mscid "mscID : nakjsxabjk1nbjk23e32jked", your script result is below
IMPU : XXXXXXXX , IMPI : YYYYYYYYY , but i need is like what I explained above...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what that means. If there's use cases not described in and not covered by the example in your question then please edit your question to fix your description and sample input/output to reflect what you really need and included cases where my answer doesn't do that.